# how to use apc in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'v just install and configured a clean copy of Symfony2 framework and included in php.ini the extension 
php_apc_319_php54_vc9_win7-2008.dll
restart apache and run the url "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/"
it was all fine until refreshing the page and getting an error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader::registerNamespaces()
>   in E:\phpWorkspace\www\Symfony\app\autoload.php on line 10.

I'v allready read [this chapter about performance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html)
but maybe I didn't use it well

I'm a novice with symfony so I will be very happy to get astep by step tutorial

Comment: Could you show us your autoload.php file?

Comment: I think your symfony version is not in sync with your app/autoload.php file.

Comment: Please find the `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` file and give us the version constant.

Comment: maybe you should use  use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader to load the class

Comment: it is a clean copy of symfony 2 version 2.0.15 so every body now the content of it except i'v just added to autoload.php this:"require __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('some caching unique prefix');" and now i'm getting the error:"Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader::registerNamespaces() in E:\phpWorkspace\www\BuyerFarm\app\autoload.php on line 10"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Apc in php

[Install apc link1](http://7php.com/linux-mint-how-to-install-apc-and-configure-apc-on-xampp-apc-caching-extension/)

[Install apc link2](http://www.samclarke.com/2011/10/install-apc-with-xampp-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess from the file you are using (php_apc_319_php54_vc9_win7-2008.dll) that this dll purports to provide APC 3.1.9 for use with PHP 5.4.  Support for PHP 5.4 wasn't added to APC until 3.1.10, and even now is only officially in beta.

At time of writing, the latest version is 3.1.13.  I would install that before investigating anything else.